# Wordpress blog doesn't show up online?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a self-hosted wordpress blog and on my ftp server everything is under

```
     /public_html/wordpress/.. 
         then you have /wp-admin and /wp-content etc..
```

but when I got to my website the theme doesn't show up, it only shows a white page with

```
    www.******.co.cc  

    " index of
    /wordpress"
```

I figured out the wordpress blog has installed its own directory so if I want to see my website I need to enter that directory first. So I tried to type

```
   www.*******.co.cc/wordpress/
```

and it worked my website is all here.

BUT ! I don't wanna have people to type www.******.co.cc/wordpress/ since the site was originially known without adding /wordpress at the end.

If I move all my wordpress folders under the root

```
   /public_html .. will it work ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory to move the site to root.

After the move, if all you see is "index of...", add

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

at the top of .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings > General 
Check your site address(url) and wordpress address(url) to make sure they are set how you want them.

The site address should have the url for where you want people to view the page (without the wordpress extension. )

You most likely also have to move your index.php and .htaccess file out of the wordpress file and into the root folder.

Go here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory and 
View the instructions under the heading "Using a pre-existing subdirectory install"

It is good to have FTP running while you do this in case you lock yourself out of the admin by inserting an incorrect filepath.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have installed your wordpress script in the

> public_html >> wordpress

Install your wordpress in the root i.e left the directory field empty

> /